# How should a Language Server Protocol Server determine the correct end of line sequence to use when inserting text into a document?

Tags: language-server-protocol

When implementing a Language Server Protocol server command that inserts lines of text into a document (i.e. by applying a `WorkspaceEdit`, for example when performing a source code action) is there a well specified way to determine whether to insert LF or CRLF to terminate each line?

So far I have the following heuristic:

- If the file contains at least one line-end character ('\n', '\r'), detect as CRLF if the file contains CRLF, otherwise LF.
- Otherwise, if the file is empty or contains no line end character, use CRLF on Windows, otherwise LF

In both of these cases there is no guarantee that the detected line ending style matches that selected by the user in the editor. And if there is no line ending in the document (such as in a new empty document) then it's just a guess.

Another solution that I am considering is to implement `.editorconfig` parsing in the language server. Obviously this is onerous and requires some juggling to ensure that the correct `.editorconifg` file versions are examined if they are under LSP control.

The question I am asking boils down to whether the LSP itself offers any solution to this problem? or failing that, is there a defacto standard approach to dealing with this problem?

Note: LSP 3.16 adds the `normalizesLineEndings` client capability, but it is unclear whether that means normalizes to LF or CRLF or whether that means the client will normalize only user entered text or also edits sent by the server. So it is unclear whether client normalization is relevant to the question of what line ending sequence the server should use when inserting lines. None the less I have asked for clarification about the meaning of `normalizesLineEndings` in an [LSP issue](https://github.com/microsoft/language-server-protocol/issues/1800).